# python subprocess stdin truncated at first space

Tags: python, go, utf-8, subprocess

I have an issue with `pOpen.communicate()` where the string I send to the subprocess truncates at the first occurrence of a space character I am sending to `STDIN` (keep in mind I am encoding to bytes using encoding `utf-8`)

Input file `text.txt`

```
this is an input string
```

My code

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# open file and encode to utf-8 bytes
fp = open('test.txt')
inputs = fp.read()
inputBytes = bytes(inputs, 'utf-8')

# open subprogram and send the bytes to STDIN
p = Popen(['./program'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input=inputBytes)

# print STDOUT of subprocess, will print what was given
out = str(stdout_data).split('\\n')
for frame in out:
    print(frame)
```

my expected output:

```
(b'this is an input string', b'')
```

what I got:

```
(b'this', b'')
```

am I using the wrong encoding format?  The subprogram is a go application that uses scanf to listen to pOpen.communicate() data

```golang
package main

import "fmt"


func main() {
    var inputs string
    fmt.Print("")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &inputs)

    fmt.Println(inputs)
}
```

Comment: this example worked for me: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/string-with-spaces/10617/4

Answer (score 1):

Go's `fmt.Scanf` is based on C's `scanf`; `%s` skips leading spaces and then reads the next word up to the first space. That's probably not what you wanted.

From the docs, a bit more precise:

> Input processed by verbs is implicitly space-delimited: the implementation of every verb except `%c` starts by discarding leading spaces from the remaining input, and the `%s` verb (and `%v` reading into a string) stops consuming input at the first space or newline character. (https://pkg.go.dev/fmt)